# Resolve optional non-jar artifacts with sbt

Tags: sbt

My company uses .zip sources for some of its libraries.  Is there any way for me to tell sbt to search for .zip extension as well as .jar?

I've tried specifying the artifact dependency explicitly through an artifacts(Artifact(...)) call, but that makes the sources required, as opposed to optional the way jar ones are.